# Is hierarchical clustering (with average-linkage and euclidean distance) deterministic?

Tags: hierarchical-clustering, deterministic

If I have a dataset called "A" and run n times a hierarchical clustering with average-linkage and euclidean distance on dataset A, will I get n equal clustering solutions (one for each run)?

Comment: Results of hierarchical clustering potentially depend on the order of cases (objects being clustered) in the dataset. This is when data have few values and so the computed distance matrix has many ties in it. This just a reminder for you, not an answer. If the order is fixed, then yes, the results are stereotypical from run to run. Hierarchical clustering does not use random value generator.

Comment: Thanks @ttnphns. How to make order fixed with python scipy?